# Making sense of a small data set

Tags: logistic, classification, small-sample, reporting

I have a small data set for a binary classification problem, with N_0=18 and N_1=11 instances in 0 and 1 classes respectively. The problem is how to make sense of the classification procedure with this tiny data set and assess the classification quality.

I compared a simple cross validated logistic regression to the dummy baseline classifier which always predicts the most prevalent class (0). Here is my code (Python with scikit-learn v0.18)

```
>> from sklearn.model_selection     import GridSearchCV
>> from sklearn.linear_model        import LogisticRegression
>> from sklearn.model_selection     import StratifiedShuffleSplit
>> from sklearn.dummy               import DummyClassifier

>> sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2)
>> parameters = {'clf__C': logspace(-4,2,100)}
>> pipe_logistic = Pipeline([('scl', StandardScaler()),('clf', LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced'))])
>> grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_logistic, param_grid=parameters, verbose=1, scoring='f1', cv=sss)
>> clf_dummy = DummyClassifier(strategy='most_frequent',random_state=0)

>> grid_search.fit(df[['f_1','f_2']], df['label'])
>> clf_dummy.fit(df[['f_1','f_2']], df['label'])

>> grid_search.score(df[['f_1','f_2']], y)
>>   0.63636363636363635
>> print confusion_matrix(y,grid_search.predict(df[['f_1','f_2']]))
>> array([[14,  4],
          [ 4,  7]])

>> clf_dummy.score(df[['f_1','f_2']], y)
>>   0.62068965517241381
>> confusion_matrix(y,clf_dummy.predict(df[['f_1','f_2']]))
>> array([[18,  0],
          [11,  0]])

>> print classification_report(y, grid_search.predict(df[['f_1','f_2']]))
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.78      0.78      0.78        18
          1       0.64      0.64      0.64        11

avg / total       0.72      0.72      0.72        29

>> print classification_report(y, clf_dummy.predict(df[['f_1','f_2']]))
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.62      1.00      0.77        18
          1       0.00      0.00      0.00        11

avg / total       0.39      0.62      0.48        29
```

Obviously, the logistic regression does better (f1 score), but their accuracies are almost the same. Here is the data I used for classification:

```
>> print df

     f_1   f_2  label
0   11.0   0.5      0
1    6.0   0.0      0
2   11.0   8.0      0
3    9.0   4.5      0
4    6.0   0.5      0
5   15.0   0.5      0
6   69.0  18.0      0
7    3.0   0.5      0
8   39.0  18.0      0
9    2.0   0.0      0
10   1.0   0.0      0
11  25.0   8.0      0
12   7.0   2.0      0
13   8.0   0.0      0
14   6.0   0.5      0
15   5.0   2.0      0
16   2.0   0.0      0
17   5.0   2.0      0
18  31.0   0.0      1
19  11.0   0.5      1
20  26.0   4.5      1
21  37.0   0.5      1
22   8.0   0.0      1
23  39.0   2.0      1
24   9.0   2.0      1
25  59.0   2.0      1
26   0.0   0.0      1
27   3.0   0.0      1
28   3.0   0.5      1
```

**Question:**

1. How to report my classification results? The accuracy of the logistic regression is almost the same as a dummy classifier, while its f1 score is singnificantly better (0.72 vs. 0.48).

   2. Should I do a nested cross validation, in order to better estimate the classification metrics?
   3. What is the best practice to work with this small data set and report correct classification results?

**Classes: Red - 0, Blue - 1**

[image]

Comment: Interesting to note that this is not the optimal linear decision boundary.  Try plotting `abline(-1.8,0.26)`